# Pickled machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, python

Is there a website where people store their pickled models for others to try? E.g. different people might try different ML approaches on the iris dataset, is there a place where I can find/download models others have constructed?

Comment: This is a nice idea, though it's much easier to outline the features, parameters and data sets than the actual pickled file which can greatly swell up in size, depending on the algorithm and size of training data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Kaggle.com, there is a [datasets section](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets). In this section, you can post or find datasets. For each dataset, you have the data, possibility to discuss about it and, of course, a list of kernels posts by the user. For instance, for the iris dataset, you have [592 kernels](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/iris/kernels) available.

Answer (score 3):

Pickled models probably will not work on a different computer. It is also a very insecure format [(see here)](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_avoid-dangerous-input-parsing-libraries.html). Rather go to kaggle.com or github.com and look for kernels/scripts that allow you to train a model on your own. Some frameworks, such as XGBoost, have a build in saving functionality with is more reliable than pickle.

Answer (score 2):

For deep learning, there are a few model hubs where folks share models that are suitable for further fine-tuning or usage in given areas. None of these will be in the pickle format (from your question), but they are great resources nonetheless:

- [PyTorch Model Hub](https://pytorch.org/hub/)
- [Tensorflow Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub)
- [Hugging Face Models](https://huggingface.co/models)